# Mongodb - stream documents with date field that has passed NOW

Tags: mongodb, scala, stream, akka

I want to use a reactive stream in mongoDB (collection.watch, maybe?) to stream data. My documents has a date property called `triggerAfter` and when that date is passed I want mongo to put the document in my stream. Is this possible to do with Mongodb?

I am using Scala and Akka to work with the streams. The current code looks like this, but it is not reactive.

```
def streamItemsByTriggerAtDate(): Source[MyDocument, NotUsed] = {
    val query = Json.obj("triggerAt" -> Json.obj("$lte" -> OffsetDatetime.now()))

    MongoSource(mongoDb.collection("myCollection").find(query))
      .map(fromDocument[MyDocument])
```

So I want Mongo to give me the items that is passing the `triggerAt` date (realtime now) when my stream is active.

Comment: are you using alpakka?

Comment: Yes, I am using that :)

Comment: Ok, you can use Alpakka alongside reactive-mongo db or reactive-mongodb with akka-stream library. Note you should have to use reactive mongo in any case

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are a lot of libraries provide that functionality. If you are using reactive-mongodb library you should take a look how `Cursor` is implemented. There are some parameters that helps you to step what you want with stream. Even if you are using alpakka-mongodb library you should reactive-mongo lib:

```
import reactivemongo.api.Cursor
import reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONDocument
import reactivemongo.api.bson.collection.BSONCollection

def events(coll: BSONCollection): AkkaStreamCursor[Int] =
    collection.find(BSONDocument.empty/* findAll */).
    sort(BSONDocument("id" -> 1)).cursor[Int]()

val src: Source[Int, Future[State]] = cursor.documentSource()
```

You can find detailed information [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/api/collections/ChangeStreamOps.scala) and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo-Streaming)